# help finding out the cause of this error in mysql partitioned table

Tags: mysql, replication, partitioning

I have a table wallet_transactions which grows very quickly. So, i have partition the table .

```
CREATE TABLE `wallet_transaction` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wallet_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ims_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bucket_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bucket_expiry` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `incoming_params` text,
  `outgoing_params` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference_id` bigint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_success_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`created`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`,`created`),
  KEY `idx_code` (`code`),
  KEY `idx_wallet_id` (`wallet_id`),
  KEY `idx_created` (`created`),
  KEY `idx_reference_id` (`reference_id`),
  KEY `idx_transaction_type` (`transaction_type`),
  KEY `idx_transaction_success_date` (`transaction_success_date`),
  KEY `idx_status` (`status`),
  KEY `idx_user_ims_id` (`ims_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20231863 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(created))
(
 PARTITION y2022w43 VALUES LESS THAN (738823) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2022w44 VALUES LESS THAN (738830) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2022w45 VALUES LESS THAN (738837) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2022w46 VALUES LESS THAN (738844) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2022w47 VALUES LESS THAN (738851) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2022w48 VALUES LESS THAN (738858) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2022w49 VALUES LESS THAN (738865) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2022w50 VALUES LESS THAN (738872) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2022w51 VALUES LESS THAN (738879) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION y2022w52 VALUES LESS THAN (739250) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

After adding partition ,

```
mysql> show open tables where in_use > 0;
+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------+
| Database | Table              | In_use | Name_locked |
+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------+
| opms     | wallet_transaction |      1 |           0 |
+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------+

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
.....
---TRANSACTION 21582106031, ACTIVE 76 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
385801 lock struct(s), heap size 34365648, 2750427 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 7070, OS thread handle 139878767720192, query id 1329063 System lock
.....
Slave lag due to the row locks
mysql> show slave status\G
  Seconds_Behind_Master: 28191
```

I added a key on index on id(PK) column to the existing DDL.

```
add key test_id (id)
```

By which got slave error 1032, updates to this table are failing

```
Could not execute Update_rows event on table opms.wallet_transaction; Can't find record in 'wallet_transaction', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.001200, end_log_pos 75994431, Error_code: 1032
```

Can anyone explain the reason it is happening.

**EDIT**

I am testing partition on a slave.
Below are the sample binlog events from the master

```
### INSERT INTO `wallet_transaction`
### SET
###   @1=20264168 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @2=NULL /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @3=8005450023590252 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @4='VjUwI2IyY2U5ODM3LWM2MGItNDgyNS1iMzVjLWZlZGU4OTI2MmE3Zg' /* VARSTRING(765) meta=765 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @5=2 /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @6=100 /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @7=NULL /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @8='INI' /* VARSTRING(30) meta=30 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @9=NULL /* BLOB/TEXT meta=2 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @10=NULL /* VARSTRING(1500) meta=1500 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @11=NULL /* VARSTRING(60) meta=60 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @12='Claim Reward' /* VARSTRING(1500) meta=1500 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @13='2021-10-29 00:01:11' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @14=NULL /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @15=NULL /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @16='CR' /* VARSTRING(135) meta=135 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @17=NULL /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */


### UPDATE `wallet_transaction`
### WHERE
###   @1=20264168 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
### SET
###   @2=2036421689 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @3=8005450023590252 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @4='VjUwI2IyY2U5ODM3LWM2MGItNDgyNS1iMzVjLWZlZGU4OTI2MmE3Zg' /* VARSTRING(765) meta=765 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @5=2 /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @6=100 /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @7='2021-11-05 00:01:11' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @8='CTD' /* VARSTRING(30) meta=30 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @9='{BillAmount=0.0, ErrorDescription=null, ResponseCode=0, TransactionType=ADD CARD TO WALLET, InvoiceNumber=null, ResponseMessage=Transaction successful., ErrorCode=null, Notes=Claim Reward, TransactionId=2036421689}' /* BLOB/TEXT meta=2 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @10='{IdempotencyKey=2036421689, Amount=100, CardProgramName= CLP Promo_Dor_D30_90_exp7, InvoiceNumber=, Notes=Claim Reward, Expiry=2021-11-05T00:01:10}' /* VARSTRING(1500) meta=1500 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @11='6812626' /* VARSTRING(60) meta=60 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @12='Claim Reward' /* VARSTRING(1500) meta=1500 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @13='2021-10-29 00:01:11' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @14='2021-10-29 00:01:12' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @15=NULL /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @16='CR' /* VARSTRING(135) meta=135 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @17='2021-10-29 00:01:12' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
```

sample events from the slave

```
### INSERT INTO `wallet_transaction`
### SET
###   @1=20231989 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @2=NULL /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @3=8005450023429267 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @4='VjUwIzEwZThiYjk0LWRhN2ItNGQ2Yi1iOGI2LWI1ZDNiYTk3MjlmNw' /* VARSTRING(765) meta=765 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @5=1 /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @6=10 /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @7=NULL /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @8=NULL /* VARSTRING(30) meta=30 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @9=NULL /* BLOB/TEXT meta=2 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @10=NULL /* VARSTRING(1500) meta=1500 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @11=NULL /* VARSTRING(60) meta=60 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @12=NULL /* VARSTRING(1500) meta=1500 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @13='2021-10-27 03:02:02' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @14=NULL /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @15=42003003 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @16='RF' /* VARSTRING(135) meta=135 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @17=NULL /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */

### UPDATE `wallet_transaction`
### WHERE
###   @1=20231989 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @13='2021-10-27 03:02:02' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
### SET
###   @2=2033189892 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @3=8005450023429267 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @4='VjUwIzEwZThiYjk0LWRhN2ItNGQ2Yi1iOGI2LWI1ZDNiYTk3MjlmNw' /* VARSTRING(765) meta=765 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @5=1 /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @6=10 /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @7=NULL /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @8='CTD' /* VARSTRING(30) meta=30 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @9='{BillAmount=0.0, ErrorDescription=null, ResponseCode=0, TransactionType=ADD CARD TO WALLET, InvoiceNumber=null, ResponseMessage=Transaction successful., ErrorCode=null, Notes=PROMOTION credit of 10, TransactionId=}' /* BLOB/TEXT meta=2 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @10='{IdempotencyKey=2033189892, Amount=10, CardProgramName= CLP Promo_Refund, InvoiceNumber=, Notes=PROMOTION credit of 10}' /* VARSTRING(1500) meta=1500 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @11='6806878' /* VARSTRING(60) meta=60 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @12=NULL /* VARSTRING(1500) meta=1500 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @13='2021-10-27 03:02:02' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @14='2021-10-27 03:02:03' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @15=42003003 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @16='RF' /* VARSTRING(135) meta=135 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @17='2021-10-27 03:02:03' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
```

**EDIT - 2:-**
Below are the queries mysql recieves on master -

```
2021-10-29T12:47:49.476393+05:30        2301738 Query   insert into wallet_transaction (amount, batch_number, bucket_expiry, bucket_id, code, created, ims_id, incoming_params, notes, outgoing_params, reference_id, status, transaction_success_date, transaction_type, updated, wallet_id) values (100, null, null, 2, null, '2021-10-29 12:47:49.476', 'VjUwIzRmYzFmYzczLTJmNGItNDlkZC1iOTJjLTU3YzA5ZGNlOGI2ZA', null, 'Claimed', null, null, 'INI', null, 'CR', null, '8005450023591371')

2021-10-29T12:47:49.624750+05:30        2301738 Query   update wallet_transaction set amount=100, batch_number='6812626', bucket_expiry='2021-11-13 12:47:49.478', bucket_id=2, code='2036783171', created='2021-10-29 12:47:49.475', ims_id='VjUwIzRmYzFmYzczLTJmNGItNDlkZC1iOTJjLTU3YzA5ZGNlOGI2ZA', incoming_params='{BillAmount=0.0, ErrorDescription=null, ResponseCode=0, TransactionType=ADD CARD TO WALLET, InvoiceNumber=null, ResponseMessage=Transaction successful., ErrorCode=null, Notes=Claimed Cash in Wallet, TransactionId=2036783171}', notes='Claimed Cash in Wallet', outgoing_params='{IdempotencyKey=2036783171, Amount=100, CardProgramName=Snapdeal CLP Promo_Dor_D30_90_exp7, InvoiceNumber=2036783171, Notes=Claimed Cash in Wallet, Expiry=2021-11-13T12:47:49}', reference_id=null, status='CTD', transaction_success_date='2021-10-29 12:47:49.622', transaction_type='CR', updated='2021-10-29 12:47:49.622', wallet_id='8005450023591371' where id=20267317
```

And here is the table definition at the master

```
CREATE TABLE `wallet_transaction` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wallet_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ims_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bucket_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bucket_expiry` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `incoming_params` text,
  `outgoing_params` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference_id` bigint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_success_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`),
  KEY `idx_code` (`code`),
  KEY `idx_wallet_id` (`wallet_id`),
  KEY `idx_created` (`created`),
  KEY `idx_reference_id` (`reference_id`),
  KEY `idx_transaction_type` (`transaction_type`),
  KEY `idx_transaction_success_date` (`transaction_success_date`),
  KEY `idx_status` (`status`),
  KEY `idx_user_ims_id` (`ims_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21388679 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: *Could not execute Update_rows event on table opms.wallet_transaction;* Show this event procedure code, point to the statement which causes the error. *I added a key* The presence of the index where specified value (id) is a prefix (PK index) makes this index creation meaningless. *PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(created))* What is the reason in expression use? why not the date itself?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As created is datetime, UNIX_TIMESTAMP is not supported. Added the events from the slave in EDIT.

Comment: @Akina - MySQL Partitions have some goofy restrictions.  _Many_ datatypes cannot be used for the partition key.  `TO_DAYS` is a simple and effective workaround for date-like datatypes.

Comment: *UNIX_TIMESTAMP is not supported.* No such datatype in MySQL. *Many datatypes cannot be used for the partition key.* All supported datatypes expressions allowed in index definition may be used for partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `BY RANGE`, always include

```
PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
```

to catch anything that is beyond 739250 (in your case) -- either explicitly or because you have not yet added the next partition.

Use `REORGANIZE PARTITION future INTO ((a new partition plus a repeated of 'future'))`

That way, you can keep any rows that accidentally landed in 'future'.

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

I should note that `PARTITION BY RANGE` is very useful when you get around to deleting the oldest partition -- it is a lot faster than `DELETE`.  But the partitioning probably provides no other performance benefit.

Other notes...

- Do you really need BIGINTs?  Each takes 8 bytes.
- KEY `idx_code` (`code`) is redundant with the UNIQUE key.
- Do you use `id` for anything?  If not, get rid of it and promote the `UNIQUE(code, created)` to be the PK.
- Indexing low-cardinality columns (eg, `status`?) is usually not useful.  Is there a query that searches by both `status` and some other column?  If so, replace that index by a multi-column ("composite") index.
- Did you see any performance benefit (because of "grows very quickly") when you switched to Partitioning?
- Once you get beyond, say, 100 partitions, you may see performance *degredation*, especially for any queries that don't include `created` in the `WHERE` clause.
- Show us the main queries so you can help with designing the indexes.
- Don't use `NULL` for everything; use `NOT NULL` where appropriate.
- `amount` int(10) -- The `(10)` has no meaning.  Furthermore, if this is Cryptocurrency, `INT` seem "wrong".  Consider `DOUBLE` for such.

Comment: Hi @Rick, I have added the binlog events. I have tested removing partitioning and all the index expect UK, 
and having a compound primary key (id,created) , still see the row locks.

Comment: @dragon - What query was running on the Replica when it lagged?

Comment: On this slave server, no queries are running from any client.

Comment: @dragon - I worry (without any proof) that having two unique keys (`PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE code`) can lead to nasties like what you are seeing.  So, my 3rd bullet item may be the answer.